# custom post on homepage

Tags: loop, buddypress

How would I include a post from a specific category on my homepage in buddypress?

Example I have a category 'Homepage Banners' with an ID of 3.

In the admin I create a post and assign the 'Homepage Banners' category to it.

I then need this to show up on the homepage (the latest post).

I am new to WP/BP, any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a new query (with php enabled) so show a single post by ID, i.e. the post with ID 101:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('p=101'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This can be used multiple times inside the WP loop without conflict.

Use [Exec-PHP « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/) or others.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Simon Forster:

I had to slightly edit your code to end up with:

```
global $wp_query;

$args = array('cat'=>3,'posts_per_page'=>1);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($my_query->have_posts()):
    $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inline posts plugin http://aralbalkan.com/wordpress

Or a plugin called ggis-InlinePost (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ggis-inline-post/) gives authors an easy way to insert a post within a page or another post. Simply add [ggisinlinepost id=”%id”] to your post. There are a few attributes to control the display of the inlined post’s title, content, metadata, and separators.